# What does an extra 0 in front of an int value mean?

Tags: c++, octal

Inspiring from a obfuscated piece of code, I have a small question regarding to assign value to an integer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
    int i = 0101;
    std::cout << i << "\n";
}
```

And the output was 65, and I have no idea where 65 came from? Any idea?

Comment: The linked duplicate is closed and generally of low quality. This question and answer however, are plain and straight-forward. I'm re-opening this with the intention to use as canonical dupe for octal literal FAQs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It specifies an octal (base-8) number: `0101 == 1 * (8 * 8) + 1 == 65`.

Comment: @:Lambert: Thanks a lot ;)! It was really interesting.

Comment: @Chan: You're welcome. :) I actually learned it myself a few hours ago, when learning about the grammar of the D language!

Comment: @Chan: The full expansion of 0101, if the extra detail helps you understand: 101 in base 8 is (each digit from left to right) `1 * (8 ** 2) + 0 * (8 ** 1) + 1 * (8 ** 0)`; this reduces to the expression in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Lambert already explained that. So let me tell you what else you can do.

You can write hexadecimal integer:

```
int main() {
    int i = 0x101; //0x specifies this (i.e 101) is hexadecimal integer
    std::cout << i << "\n"; //prints 257 (1 * 16 * 16 + 1)
}
```

Output:

```
257
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.